# Having issues adding mailalias to mailcontact with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am struggelig with adding mail-alias (secondary mail-address?) to a mailcontact in exchange. I am able to add primary SMTP and all the other attributes, but for some reason I'm struggelig with alias.

Here is the command I'm running. The command works just fine if I replace the variables with strings typed in manually (For example `"test@test.com"` instead of `$someAddress`) as you'll see in my examples below. This command does **not** work (can't even find the contact):

```
Get-Mailcontact -filter {WindowsEmailAddress -eq $SomeonesWindowsEmailAddress} -Domaincontroller $domainController | Set-Mailcontact -EmailAddresses @{ Add = "smtp:$SomeAddress","SMTP:$PrimaryAddress" } -domaincontroller $domainController

#These are example variables only, but the output of the variables would be something like:
    #$SomeonesWindowsEmailAddress outputs test.test@test.com
    #$SomeAddress outputs test.alias@test.com
```

However, this works just fine:

```
Get-Mailcontact -filter {WindowsEmailAddress -eq "test.test@test.com"} -Domaincontroller $domainController | Set-Mailcontact -EmailAddresses @{ Add = "smtp:test.alias@test.com","SMTP:test.primary@test.com" } -domaincontroller $domainController
```

I've also tried to add it this way:

```
$script:ADContact_attrib = @{
    'Name' = $contact_CN
    'Displayname' = $fullName
    'PrimarySMTPAddress' = $completeMailAddress
    'Emailaddresses' = $SomeAddress
    'ExternalEmailAddress' = $forwardMailAddress
    'FirstName' = $tb_f.txt
    'LastName' = $tb_e.txt
    'OrganizationalUnit' = $OU
}
New-MailContact @ADContact_attrib -verbose -domaincontroller $domainController
```

And this actually works with the primary smtp even if it's within a variable, but it doesn't add the `EmailAddresses` part to the mailcontact.

*(Powershell studio 2016)*

Comment: Where are you getting `$someaddress` from? Am I missing it?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I had to add that or not as I wanted to keep the code short. It's example variables only. I gather the variables from textboxes filled in within the form. It's something like `$script:SomeonesWindowsEmailAddress = $name.text + '.' + $lastname.text + '@' + 'test.no'`. $name and $lastname are textboxes. It's pretty similar how I get the $SomeAddress.

Comment: Does it throw an error or just not add it?

Comment: No errors. If I type only this part in powershell 1) `$user = "test@test.com"` then 2)  `Get-Mailcontact -filter {WindowsEmailAddress -eq $user} -Domaincontroller $domainController` it won't even list the user even though I know for sure the variable now contains the correct information. On the other hand, writing `Get-Mailcontact -filter {WindowsEmailAddress -eq "test@test.com} -Domaincontroller $domainController` works just fine. I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed reading part of your post. You cannot use PrimarySMTPAddress and EmailAddresses in the same command. I'd recommend after creating the content, just add a one liner `set-mailcontact -identity $identity -emailaddresses @{add=$someaddress}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124519(v=exchg.160).aspx) you cannot use `PrimarySMTPAddress` and `EmailAddresses` in the same command:

> The PrimarySmtpAddress parameter specifies the primary return email
>   address that's used for the recipient. If it's available on this
>   cmdlet, you can't use the EmailAddresses and PrimarySmtpAddress
>   parameters in the same command. By default, the primary address is the
>   same as the ExternalEmailAddress parameter value.

So I'd recommend doing something like

```
Set-MailContact -Identity "$tb_l, $tb_f" -emailaddresses @{add=$someaddress}
```

Although the Identity will change based on your environment. In mine, everything is Last, First.

Comment: Removing the Primary and changing the identity did work. Removing primary and not changing the filter/identity (`Get-Mailcontact -filter {WindowsEmailAddress -eq $variable}`) still don't work for some reason... I'll stick with your solution - thanks, Nick!